# RECEIVING FILE AS CLIENT in cpp-httplib

Tags: c++, client-server, file-transfer

there I am Currently using the cpp-httplib library for file transfer. I am very new and have little understanding of this library. The file upload from the client-side part was easy to understand and also had soln for it on this site too. But there aren't any references to download files from the server. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
httpServer_.Get("/Download/filename", [&](const httplib::Request& _req, httplib::Response& _res)
{
    _res.set_content("filedata", "multipart/form-data");
});
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.